# How to change shape of (5858, ) to (5858, n) in python

Tags: python, concatenation, shapes

I want to concatenate two numpy files, but they have different shape and style. The first file '640_lbp.npy', consist of list, but the second one 'train_x_test.npy' consist of array.

I got a numpy file with the shape of (5858,), now I want to change it to (5858, n), where n represent length of each row. How can I do that.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XoAb.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5AzX.png)

Comment: That will not work. Arrays have to be rectangular, and therefore cannot have different shapes depending on which row you are in.

Comment: please do not use images of code/data, please update your question with **text**

Comment: @sarema
thanks a lot. You are right. The arrays is not rectangular. I have trimmed the arrays and solved the problems.

Comment: @mozway Thanks for your suggestions. I solved the problem.

Comment: @X.Wang Glad to help. I have copied my comment into an actual answer. Please mark it as correct and upvote it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will not work. Arrays have to be rectangular, and therefore cannot have different shapes depending on which row you are in.